# ¿Por qué usar memoria dinámica?(C++)

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación, y hace ya un tiempo aprendí el uso de la memoria dinámica, me la aprendí de memoria y la deje pasar sin entender mucho su esencia y el porque se usa.

Se lo básico: la memoria se asigna en tiempo de ejecución, es trabajo del programador liberarla,trabaja con punteros, etc...

El caso es que de momento no le veo la utilidad. Siempre me ponen el mismo ejemplo en el cual se crea un vector, se le pide al usuario su tamaño y se asigna la memoria... ¿Pero esto no genera los mismo problemas que la memoria estática? Es más me parece un ejemplo horrible, pues yo podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
int size;
cout<<"Introduzca tamano"<<size; 
int vector[size];
```

y estaría haciendo una especie de memoria dinámica bastante cutre (según mis conocimientos actuales), me gustaría que me pongan algún ejemplo donde de verdad sacarle jugo al "new" y "delete". Pues hasta ahora solo uso la memoria dinámica por si quiero crear alguna variable que se que mas tarde voy a eliminar (variable temporal).

Comment: Hola. Para empezar esas tres líneas que has escrito no compilan. Primero porque no puedes definir un array estático como ese usando una variable para el tamaño. El tamaño tiene que ser una constante. Y segundo porque con eso que has hecho no estás pidiendo al usuario que introduzca nada, sino imprimiendo en la consola la cadena Introduzca tamaño seguido de lo que tenga size, que a saber qué es al no haberlo inicializado con ningún valor. Eso no pide introducción de datos. Para el tema de los punteros, te recomiendo que busques un manual y leas, más que pedir opiniones.

Answer (score 4):

> ... y estaría haciendo una especie de memoria dinámica ...

Esa *funcionalidad* tiene un nombre: VLA (Variable Length Array, Formación de tamaño variable). Tal y como dices, es una *especie* de memoria dinámica ... con 3 *ligeros* inconvenientes:

1. No forma parte de la especificación del lenguaje.

   Es una *extensión* ofrecida por muchos (por no decir todos) los compiladores, que te  permiten crear formaciones con un tamaño desconocido en tiempo de compilación: te dejan usar una *variable* para indicar el tamaño, cuando el lenguaje indica claramente que se debe usar un valor *literal* o, como mucho, el resultado de una función `constexpr`.

   ```
   int size;
   cout<<"Introduzca tamano"<<size; 
   int vector[size];
   ```

   > warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'vector'
2. La memoria así asignada **se libera automaticamente al salir de la función** en la que la asignas. Cualquier intento de retornar un puntero a esa zona de memoria es un *comportamiento indefinido*. Si puedes usarla como argumento de otras funciones, pero **nunca** puedes usar esa zona de memoria como valor a retornar.

   ```
   char *reserva( size_t size ) {
     char buff[size];
     return buff;
   }
   ```

   Si intentas usar el valor retornado por esa función, terminarás *machacando* datos que han sido colocados ahí por otras funciones.
3. Usa **espacio de pila**, una zona de memoria dedicada al almacenamiento de variables y datos con un tiempo de vida limitado ... y un **tamaño** igual de limitado. Dicho tamaño es establecido por el Sistema Operativo (o por windows, si la máquina en cuestión no tiene S.O.).

   ```
   void algo( ) {
     char unaBurrada[std::numeric_limits< size_t >::max( )] = { 0 };
     *unaBurrada = '\n';
   }
   ```

   Ese tamaño máximo, y lo que sucede si lo sobrepasas, es competencia del S.O. Algunos puede que *expandan* esa zona de memoria de forma automática (hasta cierto límite). Otros asignan el tamaño al iniciar el programa y ya no lo tocan. Incluso es posible que estés trabajando sin S.O., con lo cual no hay ninguna gestión de pila y estarás limitado a las características del hardware sobre el que trabajes.

Como ves, usar VLA no es muy buena idea, mas allá de ciertos usos puntuales. Deberías usar memoria dinámica (`new`/`delete`) siempre que:

- Necesites usar esa zona de memoria desde mas de una función.
- La memoria asignada tenga una *esperanza de vida* amplia o desconocida.
- El tamaño del bloque a usar sea superior a cierto límite (esto depende del S.O.). Personalmente, suelo establecer mi límite en 4K (4096 bytes). Es un número arbitrario tan bueno como cualquier otro :-)

Por otra parte, la memoria dinámica no es la panacea. Su uso también depende del S.O. y también presenta ciertos inconvenientes, que podemos resumir en 1 solo:

- Es lenta.

La gestión de la memoria dinámica no es baladí. Es un tema amplio, que presenta varios problemas graves y que cada S.O. / Compilador ha resuelto de una u otra manera:

1. Fragmentación.

   La memoria se usa por *trozos* de tamaño discreto. Eso conlleva el riesgo de que el trozo pedido sea mas grande que el mayor trozo disponible ... aunque la suma de trozos disponibles sea mayor que el tamaño requerido.
2. Sincronización entre hilos.

   Cuando tu aplicación tiene varios hilos, cualquiera de ellos puede pedir memoria en cualquier momento. La gestión de memoria tiene que soportar esta circunstancia, por lo que suele utilizar mecanismos de bloqueo (detienen todas las solicitudes de memoria excepto aquella que se está procesando en un momento dado).

Como ves, el tema de la gestión de memoria da para escribir mas de 1 libro, y no hay un método *general y universal* que usar como guía. Tu aplicación tendrá sus propias necesidades, que no serán las mismas que las de otra.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Pero esto no genera los mismo problemas que la memoria estática?

La memoria estática **no existe**. Simplificando bastante, un programa usa dos tipos de memoria: la pila (*stack*) y el montón (*heap*).

**La pila**

La pila es una región de memoria utilizada por el propio programa para gestionar las llamadas a funciones. La gran ventaja de usar la pila es que los objetos se destruyen automáticamente cuando la ejecución abandona su ámbito, mientras que su gran desventaja es que su tamaño es muy limitado.

**El montón**

La memoria dinámica es de uso libre. La única restricción de tamaño la marca la propia memoria RAM que tengas instalada en el equipo. Como contrapartida, la gestión de los recursos almacenados en la memoria dinámica corre a cargo del programador... es decir, tu creas los objetos que necesitas cuando los necesitas y tu te encargas de destruir esos objetos a mano cuando ya no sean necesarios.

> Es más me parece un ejemplo horrible, pues yo podría hacer lo siguiente

Podrías hacerlo... pero ese código tiene varios inconvenientes:

- Si el usuario introduce un número lo suficientemente grande desbordarás la pila y el programa fallará irremediablemente. Tampoco puedes acotar el tamaño porque no tienes forma de saber cuánto espacio libre queda en la pila.
- El código de tu ejemplo **no es válido en C++**. Estás usando lo que se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y esta característica **no está soportada** por el estándar, por lo que ese código podría perfectamente no compilar. El problema de ese ejemplo es que el tamaño de los arrays debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación y eso es imposible en tu caso. Pasar ese array a funciones también puede darte dolores de cabeza.

Adicionalmente, tu ejemplo presenta ciertas limitaciones que lo hacen inviable en multitud de ocasiones

- Tu array no puede redimensionarse, es decir, no hay forma de ampliar su tamaño ni de reducirlo.
- Tu array no sirve para crear listas enlazadas, árboles ni cualquier otra estructura de datos dinámica (su grafo depende de condiciones dictadas en tiempo de ejecución)
- No puedes liberar la memoria asociada al array libremente.
- Si una función crea ese array no puede devolverlo de ninguna manera:

  ```
  int* CrearVector()
  {
    int size;
    cout<<"Introduzca tamano"<<size; 
    int vector[size];

    return vector;
  } // vector se destruye al llegar a este punto

  int main()
  {
    int* ptr = CrearVector(); // ptr apunta a memoria no válida
  }
  ```

Así que disculpa si mi punto de vista es justo el opuesto al tuyo, es decir, tu código me parece un ejemplo horrible.

La memoria dinámica no es mala *per se*, de hecho en muchos casos es la única solución a nuestro problema:

- Una aplicación de mapas GPS: El grafo de las carreteras, pese a no ser dinámico (no debería cambiar durante la ejecución del programa), dificilmente va a entrar en la pila del programa.
- Libreta de direcciones: Ejemplo de un programa que no va a consumir demasiada memoria. A priori no sabes cuántas personas va a registrar cada usuario. ¿Estableces un límite de fábrica? No parece la opción más sensata si quieres que tu aplicación tenga público.
- Paint: No solo no puedes conocer el tamaño de la imagen en tiempo de compilación sino que además, hay imágenes que se pueden comer la pila de tu programa con extrema facilidad.

Ahora bien, no siempre es necesario usar la memoria dinámica *a pelo*. Existen utilidades, como los *smart pointers*, los contenedores de la STL o la clase `std::string` que encapsulan los usos de la memoria dinámica.